# random variables-Probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

X is a random variables not negative satisfy $E[X^a]<\infty$ with $a>0$.Prove
$$E[X^a]=a\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} x^{a-1}(1-F(x))dx$$.

Comment: Start with the definition of $E[X^a]$ and try integration by parts ... Please post your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
X^a=\int_{0}^\infty a x^{a-1
} I(X>x)\, dx$$
Take expectations of both sides and use Tonell's theorem to deduce the result.